# Forward only one flowfile from multiple same flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

I have multiple flowfile as an output of spitjson processor , all are same flowfile with same content . I just want to forward one flowfile . Is there a way to do that in nifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it should be possible.

`splitjson` processor write `fragment.index` attribute to each flowfile

> A one-up number that indicates the ordering of the split FlowFiles
> that were created from a single parent FlowFile

each flowfile will receive a unique `fragment.index` starting from `1` to number of flowfile

so you can use route on attribute to only keeper flowfile with `fragment.index` equal to 1

Flow :

[image]

input data :

```
[{"name":"Gayle Hays"},{"name":"Merritt Calhoun"},{"name":"Tamara Lane"},{"name":"Contreras Heath"},{"name":"Martinez Watson"}]
```

`RouteOnAttribute` processor configuration:

[image]

Documentation : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html

Comment: thanks but one problem is that there are 30+ flowfiles after split and there is one route on attribute which routes 9+ flowfiles i want to get one of them .. but in that case how can we be sure of fragment index ??

Comment: if you only want 1 of them, you can use my routeOnAttribute configuration. otherwhise make your custom logic.i have updated my answer